# How to start setxkbmap with systemd

Tags: systemd

I'm using ubuntu 16.10. I created a file `/lib/systemd/system/setxkbmap.service` with the following contents.

```
[Unit]
Description=setxkbmap
After=lightdm.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=searene
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option 'caps:ctrl_modifier'
Environment=DISPLAY=:0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`searene` is my user name on ubuntu.

I enabled it.

```
sudo systemctl enable setxkbmap.service
```

I can make it work by running the following command.

```
sudo systemctl start setxkbmap.service
```

But I cannot make it work automatically when system boots up. I got an error saying `Cannot open display ":0"`, why? What went wrong?

By the way, when I ran the command `echo $DISPLAY` in `gnome-terminal`, the result is `:0`.

Answer (score 1):

Modify `/etc/default/keyboard`, change

```
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

to

```
XKBOPTIONS="caps:ctrl_modifier"
```

reboot, it will work.

Comment: There are more details at http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326804/5132

Comment: OMG I've spent years to find the solution, it finally works, thx!